# Classifying rows of data by the number of days to close

Tags: c#, null, statistics, .net-datatable

DataTable looks like below

[image]

I would like to simplify this code in a better manner.

```
DataTable dt = results.Results[0].DataTable;
dt.Columns.Add("Averagedays", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("0to3", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("4to7", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Gtrthan7", typeof(string));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (row["total_daysclose"] != System.DBNull.Value && row["closed_in0to3_count"] != System.DBNull.Value
        && row["closed_in4to7_count"] != System.DBNull.Value && row["closedGtr7_count"] != System.DBNull.Value
        && row["Closed"] != System.DBNull.Value)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDecimal(row["closed"]) > 0)
        {
            decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(row["total_daysclose"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(row["Closed"]);
            row["Averagedays"] = string.Format("{0:0.#}", Math.Floor(value * 10) / 10);
            row["0to3"] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row["closed_in0to3_count"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(row["Closed"]));
            row["4to7"] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row["closed_in4to7_count"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(row["Closed"]));
            row["Gtrthan7"] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row["closedGtr7_count"]) / Convert.ToDecimal(row["Closed"]));

        }
        else
        {
            row["Averagedays"] = string.Format("{0:0.#}", 0);
            row["0to3"] = string.Format("{0:P1}", 0);
            row["4to7"] = string.Format("{0:P1}", 0);
            row["Gtrthan7"] = string.Format("{0:P1}", 0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more background? What is the goal of this code? Where do the data come from — an SQL query? If so, could you include the query (and the schema, if it is necessary to help us understand the query)?

Comment: @200_success that is complex stored procedure.attached the screenshot of resultant output of the query.

Comment: I strongly suspect that a proper optimization of the datatable code should start with analyzing the stored procedure that produced the mess to begin with. Perhaps you should post a related question about the stored procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Heslacher's review, I'd also move the initial if-check to a separate function:

```
private bool IsRowInvalid(DataRow row)
{
    return row["total_daysclose"] == System.DBNull.Value 
           || row["closed_in0to3_count"] == System.DBNull.Value
           ||row["closed_in4to7_count"] == System.DBNull.Value 
           || row["closedGtr7_count"] == System.DBNull.Value 
           ||row["Closed"] == System.DBNull.Value;
}
```

This method you then call like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (IsRowInvalid(row))
    {
        continue;
    }

    // other logic here
}
```

I would also rethink names like "0to3" and "total_daysclose" if possible: these naming styles are inconsistent and IMHO bad; I'd much prefer "ZeroToThree" and "TotalDaysClose". "Gtrthan7" is even worse, since it contains an abbreviation and I really can't see any reason why.

Note that I would also move column names to constants, perhaps even move those to a static class, e.g.

```
internal static class ColumnName
{
    public const string AverageDays = "AverageDays";
    public const string Closed = "Closed";
}
```

I didn't implement this in the method above because it was too much work.

---

I just noticed your edit, and I'm wondering whether the NULL checks are even necessary, since I don't see any NULLs in your sample output. I also agree with the comments that this code indicates issues elsewhere, and that simply focusing on this method is not enough.

Comment: Nice answer, I would only reverse the `IsRowInvalid` to `IsRowValid`. I'm more a fan of positive checks and in this case you wouldn't need the `continue`. :)

Comment: I had it as `IsValid`, but then you'd still have the code nested inside an `if`; I prefer the `continue`. Also `IsValid` changes to return to the same logic as the first `if` in the original code, and I wasn't too keen on that.

Answer (score 3):

**Creation of the additional columns**

You should change the way you are adding the additional columns. By setting the `DefaultValue property` you simplify the `for` loop.

> ```
> dt.Columns.Add("Averagedays", typeof(string));
> dt.Columns.Add("0to3", typeof(string));
> dt.Columns.Add("4to7", typeof(string));
> dt.Columns.Add("Gtrthan7", typeof(string));
> ```

should be changed to

```
dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn(averageDays, typeof(String)) { DefaultValue = string.Format("{0:0.#}", 0) });
dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn(range0To3, typeof(String)) { DefaultValue = string.Format("{0:P1}", 0) });
dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn(range4To7, typeof(String)) { DefaultValue = string.Format("{0:P1}", 0) });
dt.Columns.Add( new DataColumn(gtrthan7, typeof(String)) { DefaultValue = string.Format("{0:P1}", 0) });
```

**Style**

You should extract the current and `new` columnnames to const variables.

`Const String averageDays = "Averagedays";`
`Const String closed = "closed";`
....
`row[averageDays] =`
`row[closed] =`

This is less errorprone because if you then type it wrong for e.g `row[]` the compiler will warn you.You already have a spelling error there-> `closed` vs. `Closed`.

**If..else**

You should extract the value of `row[closed]` to a variable as you need this often.

Like

```
decimal closedValue = Convert.ToDecimal(row[closed]);  
if (closedValue > 0)
{
    decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(row[totalDaysClose]) / closedValue ;
    row[averageDays] = string.Format("{0:0.#}", Math.Floor(value * 10) / 10);

    row[range0to3] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row[closed_in0to3_count]) / closedValue);
    row[range4to7] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row[closed_in4to7_count]) / closedValue);
    row[gtrthan7] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row[closedGtr7_count]) / closedValue);

}
```

Update inspired by [BCdotNET](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/10582/bcdotnet)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/71749/29371)

By using the `IsRowInvalid()` method which **BCdotNET** suggested, you can change the loop to

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows.Where(r=> !IsRowInvalid(r))
{

    decimal closedValue = Convert.ToDecimal(row[closed]);  
    if (closedValue > 0)
    {
        decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(row[totalDaysClose]) / closedValue ;
        row[averageDays] = string.Format("{0:0.#}", Math.Floor(value * 10) / 10);

        row[range0to3] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row[closed_in0to3_count]) / closedValue);
        row[range4to7] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row[closed_in4to7_count]) / closedValue);
        row[gtrthan7] = string.Format("{0:P1}", Convert.ToDecimal(row[closedGtr7_count]) / closedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other two answers, you may want to use the [DataRow.IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fwatee0(v=vs.110).aspx) method within **BCdotNET**'s `IsRowInvalid()` method:

```
private bool IsRowInvalid(DataRow row)
{
    return row.IsNull("total_daysclose")
           ||row.IsNull("closed_in0to3_count")
           ||row.IsNull("closed_in4to7_count")
           ||row.IsNull("closedGtr7_count")
           ||row.IsNull("Closed");
}
```

The method handles both `DBNull.Value` and `null` values, and it is a little easier to read.